# Replacing nn.Upsample with alternative upsample operation

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network, deconvolution

I have a [UNet++](https://towardsdatascience.com/biomedical-image-segmentation-unet-991d075a3a4b)(*view in private, code for model at the bottom of the article*) which I'm trying to reconfigure. I'm getting some artifacts in some images so I'm following [this article](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/) which suggests doing upsampling then a convolution operation.

I'm replacing the up-sample layers with sequential operation shown below but my model isn't learning. I suspect its to do with how I've configured the channels so I'd like another opinion.

**Old up-sample operation:**

```
self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True)
```

**New operations:**

```
class upConv(nn.Module):
"""
Up sampling/ deconv block by factor of 2 
"""
def __init__(self, in_ch, out_ch):
    super().__init__()
    self.upc = nn.Sequential(
                             nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode='bilinear', align_corners=True),
                             nn.Conv2d(in_ch, out_ch*2, 3, stride=1, padding=1),
                             nn.BatchNorm2d(out_ch*2),
                             nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
                             )
def forward(self, x):
    out = self.upc(x)
    return out
```

My question is do these two operations have the same output/function within my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do these two operations have the same output/function within my model?

If `out_ch*2 == in_ch`, then: yes, they have the same output shape.

If the input `x` is the output of a `BatchNorm+ReLU` op, then they could be even more similar.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, `x` does indeed come from a `conv+BatchNorm+ReLU` operation. Looks like this issue is rooted somewhere else.